# How in Ansible use "in" for nested lists in a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to build a condition for launching a role so that it runs only on servers whose variable matches the values from the list in another variable.

How does it work:

Var:

```
architecture:
  WebSphere:
    block_was_cluster_1:
      - cell
      - cell2
    block_was_cluster_2:
      - cell3
      - cell4
```

And task:

```
- name: Install
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  roles:
     - { role: download, when: type in architecture.WebSphere.block_was_cluster_1 }
```

In this case, the role will be launched on servers where the variable type = cell or cell2.

The question is, how do I set the condition so that the role starts on all servers where type = cell or cell2 or cell3 or cell4, that is, considering all the nested lists in "architecture.WebSphere"

I tried to make a condition:

```
when: type in architecture.WebSphere.items
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"How do I set the condition so that the role starts on all servers where type = cell or cell2 or cell3 or cell4, that is, considering all the nested lists in 'architecture.WebSphere'?"*

A: Use *json_query*. For example

```
   - debug:
        msg: "{{ architecture.WebSphere|json_query('*')|flatten }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} is in the architecture"
      loop:
        - cell
        - cell4
        - cell9
      when: item in architecture.WebSphere|json_query('*')|flatten
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "cell", 
        "cell2", 
        "cell3", 
        "cell4"
    ]
}

ok: [localhost] => (item=cell) => {
    "msg": "cell is in the architecture"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=cell4) => {
    "msg": "cell4 is in the architecture"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=cell9)
```

Comment: Thanks again, it worked! I had to switch to ansible >= 2.5 but this is not a problem, it's even better